# ChromeDevTools in selenium, waiting for response bodies

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I need to work on ajax response, that is one of responses received upon visiting a page. I use selenium dev tools and java. I create a listener, that intercepts a specific request and then I want to work on response it brings. However I need to setup static wait, or else selenium don't have time to save `RequestId`. I read Chrome Dev Tools documentation, but it's a new thing for me. I wonder if there is a method that would allow me to wait for this call to be completed, other than the static wait.

Here is my code:

```
    @Test(groups = "test")
    public void x() throws InterruptedException, JsonProcessingException {
        User user = User.builder();
        ManageAccountStep manageAccountStep = new ManageAccountStep(getDriver());
        DashboardPO dashboardPO = new DashboardPO(getDriver());
        manageAccountStep.login(user);
        DevTools devTools = ((HasDevTools) getDriver()).maybeGetDevTools().orElseThrow();
        devTools.createSessionIfThereIsNotOne();
        devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
        // end of boilerplate
        final RequestId[] id = new RequestId[1];
        devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), response -> {
            log.info(response.getResponse().getUrl());
            if (response.getResponse().getUrl().contains(DESIRED_URL)){
                id[0] = response.getRequestId();
            }
        });
        dashboardPO
                .clickLink(); // here is when my DESIRED_URL happens 
        Utils.sleep(5000); // Something like Thread.sleep(5000)
        String responseBody = devTools.send(Network.getResponseBody(id[0])).getBody();
        // some operations on responseBody
        devTools.clearListeners();
        devTools.disconnectSession();
    }
```

If I don't use 5 seconds wait `id` variable gets never assigned and I null pointer exception `requestId is required`. During these 5 seconds `log.info` prints all api calls that are happening and it almost always finds my `id`. I would like to refrain from static wait though. I am thinking about something similiar to maybe `jQuery.active()==0`, but my page doesn't use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try custom function Explicit Wait. Something like this:

```
public String getResponseBody(WebDriver driver, DevTools devTools) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver,5)
      .ignoring(NullPointerException.class)
      .until(driver -> 
      devTools.send(Network.getResponseBody(id[0])).getBody());
}
```

So, it won't wait for all 5 seconds. The moment it got the data, it would come of out of the until method. Also add whichever Exception that was coming up here.

Has put these lines of code as separate method because, devTools object is locally defined. In order to use them inside this anonymous inner function, it has to be final or effectively final.

Comment: Thanks! Actually inlining method works very well, compiler whines about RequestId being final or effectively final, but that have already been solved.

Comment: Can someone please provide the detailed code after you implemented the fix suggested by @Ahamed. I am also struggling in the same phase and the entire code would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to run into this issue when running tests in parallel (and headless) and trying to capture the requests and responses, I get:

{"No data found for resource with given identifier"},"sessionId" ...

However, now .until seems to only take ExpectedCondition

So a similar solution (to the accepted answer), but without using "WebDriverWait.until" that I use is:

```
public static String getResponseBody(DevTools devTools, RequestId id) {
    String requestPostData = "";
    LocalDateTime then = LocalDateTime.now();
    String err = "";
    Integer it = 0;
    while (true) {
        err = "";
        try{requestPostData = devTools.send(Network.getResponseBody(id)).getBody();} catch( Exception e){err = e.getMessage();};
        if (requestPostData != null && !requestPostData.equals("")) {break;}
        if (err.equals("")) {break;} // if we don't have an error message, its quite possible the responseBody really is an empty string
        long timeTaken = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(then, LocalDateTime.now());
        if (timeTaken >= 5) {requestPostData = err + ", timeTaken:" + timeTaken; break;}
        if(it > 0) {TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(it);} // I prefer waiting longer and longer, avoiding stack overflows
        it++;
    }
    return requestPostData;
}
```

It just loops until it doesn't error, and returns the string back as soon as it can (but I actually set timeTaken >= 60 due to many parallel requests)